# Convert bytearray containing unicode data to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding

I need to convert a bytearray which contains non-encoded raw unicode data to an unicode string, e.g. the unicode \u2167 represents the roman number 8:

```
print(u'\u2167')
Ⅷ
```

having this information stored in a bytearray I need to find a way to convert it back to unicode. Decoding from e.g. 'utf8' obviously does not work:

```
b = bytearray([0x21,0x67])
print(b.decode('utf8'))
!g
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

@Luke's comment got me on the right track. Apparently the original data (not the simplified one I am showing here) is encoded as UTF-16le. The data is obtained from a wxpython TextDataObject. wxpython internally usually uses unicode. That is what made me think that I am dealing with unicode data.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to help you here.  You've given only two bytes of your data: are all characters represented using two-byte pairs?  Your single-character example decodes correctly if you write `print(b.decode("utf-16be"))`, but it would only work more generally if you are using UTF-16BE throughout your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... a bytearray which contains non-encoded raw unicode data

If it is in a bytearray, it is by definition encoded.  The Python `bytes` or `bytearray` types can contain encoded Unicode data.  The `str` type contains Unicode code points.  You `.decode` a byte string to a Unicode string, and `.encode` a Unicode string into byte strings.  The encoding used for your example is UTF-16BE:

```
>>> b = bytearray([0x21,0x67])
>>> b.decode('utf-16be')
'Ⅷ'
```

Comment: I agree that by definition the content of a bytearray is encoded. But is is not impossible to store plain unicode data in a bytearray. The fact that the there is no numeric difference between `\u2167` and its utf-16be encoded bytearray put me on the wrong track.

Comment: @ChristianK That's an encoding :)  Unicode code points are just numbers.  The encoding defines how to store those numbers as bytes.  Code points range from 0-1113111 which won't all fit in two bytes.  UTF-16BE defines how to store the whole range.

Answer (score 0):

The line `print(b.decode('utf8'))` is not correct, correct usage is :

```
print(b.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Actually both are ok, and moreover 'UTF8' and 'UTF-8' are fine as well.

Comment: I mentioned it because the documentation only shows `utf-8`

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)  lists `utf8` as an alias for `utf-8`.